# Packed structures not compatible between 32 bit and 64 bit program?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I've got some data files that were written by a Visual C++ program (32 bit) with the structure alignment set to /Zp2.  (Just a dump of a big typedef structure). Now I want to read those files using a 64 bit program, also in Visual C (but 2017 vs 2010). If I set the alignment here to /Zp2 for some reason it is crashing another library that I use, so the alignment is set to default, and I have put #pragma pack (2) in front of all the structures that I need.  This does not seem to work however, when I try to access structure members, the data is off.  Is there something I am missing or is this not going to be possible?

Comment: Let's see the definition of the structure. Most probably, your structure has members of some other struct, whose packing must be fixed as well.

Comment: Might be something like that - the first member of the struct is an array of pointers, where each element points to another structure which I have allocated memory for. So I guess the old program would allocate 32 bit pointers, vs 64 bit for the new? Is there a way to force a pointer to be 32 bit?

Comment: Uh that's a bigger problem, pointers cannot be reliably dumped and re-loaded from file, so that shouldn't work even in the old program. Again, post the actual structure, without it it's difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: Its OK, I can skip over the pointer arrays, I'm not using them anyway for this purpose.  So I think I'm good, thanks.